# what is the closed form of the recurrence : T(n) = aT(n/2) + dn^n

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

i am trying to solve the recurrence $T(n) = aT(n/2) + dn^n$. and  here is my trial::

$n^{log_b(a)} =  n^{lg(a)}$  since $b=2$

But $n^n/{n^{lg(a)}}= n^{n-lg(a)}$ is NOT polynomially bounded and therefore Master Theorem can't be applied. so, i use the recursion tree method and i end with the followinf recurrence ::

$T(n) = d\sum a^id(n/2^i)^{n/2^i} + \theta(n^{lg(a)})$ where $i = 0: lg(n) - 1$

is that true ?? and if it is , what is the closed form of this summation ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the base case of the recurrence? Is n restricted?

Comment: $T(1) = \Theta(1)$

Comment: You ask for "closed form", but what you're *actually* looking for is "asymptotic estimate", right?

Comment: you are right..

Answer (score 0):

$n^n$ is really, *really* big; nothing else in the problem matters.

$$ T(n) = \Theta(n^n) $$

Once you realize that, the problem is fairly straightforward.

---

Incidentally, this *is* coverred by some forms of the Master theorem, such as [case three at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Master_theorem&oldid=747036611#Case_3)

Comment: I liked your last edit. :)

Comment: actually, i realized that and it takes me to another question:: is $n^n+ (n/2)^{n/2} + ... + 1 = \theta(n^n)$

Comment: in polynomials, all lower terms are ignored , but is it the same for exponentials ??